# Very unusual-shaped piece - large octagon, recessed, with alternating panels and 4 stud sections

Tags: part-identification

Does anyone know the name or number for this Lego part. I've searched and searched but can't find it:

[image: large octagon, recessed, with alternating panels and 4 stud sections]

Answer (score 10):

This is part [2618 - Cockpit 10 x 10 x 4 Octagonal with Axle Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2618&name=Cockpit%2010%20x%2010%20x%204%20Octagonal%20with%20Axle%20Hole&category=%5BCockpit%5D#T=C) which was produced from 1999 to 2009 and comes in 8 sets.

Comment: Thank you so much, Phil! You are an absolute diamond!

Comment: @rez9000 If the answer has helped you, please mark it as [accepted](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).